# Why was "graphics designer" included as type of software developer in the 2017 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey

One of the options for ["Developer Role" in the 2017 Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=hero-home#developer-profile-developer-type) was "Graphics Designer".

#### Since when is a graphics designer a software developer?

Sure, their output is *displayed* by software and most use software in their work, but what they produce isn't *itself* software. By definition they do not develop software. What they do falls into the "content developer" bucket, which includes:

- text of bloggers
- videos of vloggers
- T+C's created by corporate lawyers that must be accepted before installing software
- audio content such as music/sound effects for games
- creative writing such as house descriptions by realtors
- survey results composers

The list is endless, and nothing in that list involves developing software, so they shouldn't be part of a software development survey.

---

If through some logic "graphics designers" *are* "software developers" then so should every other job in a very long list of jobs that create content.

Comment: Just a thought - considering the question was "select all that apply", maybe they were interested in identifying developers who also are responsible for graphic design

Comment: Because it pays more of course.

Comment: @Hans and being a lawyer pays way more than a graphics designer, so what?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can juggle and play guitar (although not at the same time) - should we have those as "select all that apply" options too? Also, I've never encountered a good dev that is a good graphics designer (who IMHO are essentially digital *artists*)

Comment: My money is on the 'multiple options' and 'employers are interested in saving money by hiring devs that can do design too'. All other survey questions are heavily geared towards 'what employers are looking for'. That in your experience being able to do both means you are not good at either, is neither here nor there, if employers want to spend money on that then that's their choice.

Comment: @Mart but why graphic design and not any other of the myriad of "bonus" skills devs can have? Graphics design is not software development period. Even if it's an "extra skill" employers seek, IMHO it shouldn't get its own "developer type" in the developer survey.

Comment: Because in web dev houses that is a skill that matters? I've worked in such companies, luckily the ones that hire dedicated designers; but together with 'full stack' that's the skill profile they look for. Not for any other bonus skills.

Comment: @mart OK, make sense. I would prefer it to be in a "Can also" section, along with other useful things like business analysis, team lead, mentor, etc (which are all in practically every JD)

Comment: @MartijnPieters : In my experience, it's mostly smaller companies who combine graphic design & frontend development in one job profile. And the kind of person they prefer to fill such a position is not the "frontend developer with graphic design skills" but the "graphic designer with frontend coding skills".

Comment: @JohnSlegers: you may be correct. It's been a long time since I worked in such a shop, but the graphic designers were expected to know how to use HTML even then.

Comment: Maybe they want you to know the [Piet programming language](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) :-)

Comment: I bet everyone who downvoted this is a graphic designer ;)

Comment: Ask this [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns).

Comment: By this same logic, why is Database Administrator on the list? Systems administrator?

Comment: And Other? I mean, Other? Are you kidding? I worked as an Other, and I never touched a keyboard :P.

Comment: @mike Both DBA (I used to be one) and sysadmin write code. And plenty of it. They are software developers for sure.

Comment: Out of interest - if you've got someone working on a game who's creating a lot of graphical assets but is also taking responsibility for transforming those assets, using Python to script a fair chunk of the work, would you tell them that they we're *wrong* if they described themselves as a graphics designer?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever IMHO they are primarily a graphics designer that also does something like "graphic content transformation". I wouldn't call them a "software developer", even though they are writing python code. If writing a JD, I would put "graphics designer. experience automating transformation using python or similar required". But that's just my view on it. What I am sure of is if they aren't writing code, they aren't developing software

Comment: There is a big difference between the "title" one has, and the work one actually does. Including "graphic designer" as an option just confuses the whole survey. They should have including only options which involve actually writing code, and asked people to select, based on what they actually do. If one doesn't actually write code (regardless of their title), they shouldn't be taking the survey... And if one does write code, they should be selecting an option that makes sense. Next they'll be including steve jobs and that british guy as software developers....

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: To be honest, I select **Other**, simply because all other categories do not seem to reflect what I do. I develop programs that run on a server (so Desktop/Mobile are out) but do not power a website (so Web Developer is out). And the remaining choices are a smorgasbord of specific activities. The *closest* might be embedded, I guess, but our servers are top-of-the-line x86_64 with GBs of RAM/disk. So I pick "Other", and wonder who else does.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "backend developer"? That's the category I put myself in BTW

Comment: @Bohemian: That's what I would pick, if there wasn't this pesky "Web" stuck in the middle. I'm not a "Back-end Web Developer", I don't develop for the web. Not that I have anything against Back-end Web Developers, mind; but I did it for a time, and the job is quite different.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't dev for web either. Actually neither do many other I know. it was very narrow minded to add "web" - who cares about the client? A backend dev is a backend dev. Maybe I should ask that as s meta question: Why limit backend dev to only "web" - do they think every server app drives a web site? Hardly. A better way to do it would be to have a check boxes for "I write code that supports a web site", "I write front end code", "I write backend code"

Comment: @Bohemian: I'd support the idea of removing "Web" here, or to offer a separate category if separating Web from non-Web matters.

Comment: If they are on [SO], they should be able to check a box. Labels are secondary.

Comment: It didn't call out software developer, it said Developers, and people do develop graphics.  There was no category for Service Developer (say ESB Development that has 0 UI), BizTalk?   Graphics Design is a huge part of most software projects, and thus deserves a place at the table for those people that design web templates / UI / UX

Comment: I have people in my team who are designers but they write CSS code (or better said, SASS code). They also write angular and react code when prototyping. They use stack overflow.

Comment: @Sulthan then they're front end devs *and* they design graphics. When they're designing graphics they are not developing software.

Comment: @Ryan I disagree. As per the question, designing graphics is developing "content", which includes lots of stuff, all important. I'm not saying raphics designers are not important, I saying they are not **software** developers. And they **don't** use stackoverflow when designing graphics - that would be off-topic.

Comment: @Bohemian I agree designers are not software developers, but they are developers. The survey, to my knowledge, wasn't targeting "software develoers", because they had System Admins on there. Yes, Stack Overflow has a plethora of questions targeting software development, it also has a fair number of photoshop questions, design questions, graphic questions. So if the survey was going to target System Admins, why not graphic designers?

Answer (score 29):

Quite a number of the places I've worked the folks holding the title of 'Graphic Designer', 'Web Designer', 'UX/UI Designer' and similar - were also Front-end developers in some capacity.

Some of them were blatantly awful, and would give me static HTML to work from that was just nested tables so I'd have to redo it, but a few specific others were the best front-end developers I've ever worked with.

Some designers are developers - just like some academic research professionals, or sysadmins are also developers.

Comment: If the goal of this question was to determine what we were thinking when we came up with the list, then this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @kevin I didn't think the person who came up the the list was thinking clearly, or at all. For example, the survey also assumed that the only kind of server dev was *web* server dev (no other option was given), which is extremely narrow minded to the point of ignorance. That, combined with thinking that "graphics designer" is a "developer", leads me to suspect that the person who created the list believes that all software development is for the web, and that anyone "contributing to the web site" is a "developer".

Comment: @Bohemian At the end of the day, developing lists like that comes down to anticipating what options are likely to be selected by large numbers of respondents.  Of respondents who primarily identified as professional developers, 3.9% went on to choose "graphic designer" as a descriptor.  As for non-web-centric options, we'll be looking carefully at the write-ins for this Q for future surveys, and welcome feedback from the community.

Answer (score -1):

In the creation of websites & web applications, graphic designers play a big role in determining the structural architecture and layout of a website or web app, alongside frontend web developers, backend web developers & UX experts.

And especially in smaller companies, graphic designers are not just responsible for creating the graphics of a website in eg. Illustrator or Photoshop, but also for building skeleton templates in HTML/CSS (and sometimes even a little JavaScript) that is then used by frontend an/or backend web developers as a foundation for the layout of the website or web app.

So while graphic designers technically aren't developers, they often are involved throughout the development process, including the functional design stage, the technical design stage as well as the implementation stage. They often do have to write code, albeit usually only HTML & CSS.

Comment: Similar could be said of project managers, business analysts, testers, etc, all of which are intimately involved with the development process, but are not themselves developers. Regarding HTML/CSS/JS sure, but make that the category then.

Comment: @Bohemian : It's rare for project managers, business analysts, testers, etc. to actually write code on a daily basis. This is not the case for graphical designers. While it's less common in bigger companies, it's very common in smaller companies to combine graphic design with at least some frontend coding.

Comment: IMHO, a job involving design, building html/css templates and javascript should be labelled as front-end developer not graphics designer, and should contain graphic design as a job attribute.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin : I'm refering to jobs that have the profile "graphic designer with frontend coding skills", not the profile "frontend developer with graphic design skills". This means the focus is on the graphic design, not on the coding. The people hired are graphic designers. They just happen to also do the HTML, the CSS & sometimes a bit of JavaScript, but that's not the main focus of their job.

Comment: I'd say that the "little Javascript" may apply, but HTML/CSS is *not* software development in the same way that creating a postscript document isn't software development.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : That's a semantic distinction that's pretty arbitrary IMO. For example, what about people who use SCSS as a preprocessor language? SCSS, as a language, is pretty close to being Turing complete (if not there already). Does that mean coding in SCSS is development but not coding in CSS? Are you saying SCSS coders ARE software developers but CSS coders AREN'T? On what grounds do you make your distinction between software development and... well... everything else?

Comment: @JohnSlegers I was thinking about turing-completeness, yes, though I'm willing to compromise for "near". Is HTML/CSS (without Javascript) anything near turing-complete? Maybe HTML5 but I seriously doubt that people who can write turing machine equivalent code in HTML5 are considered "graphic designers".

Comment: @RealSkeptic : Many (if not most) graphic designers don't write their selectors directly in CSS anymore. Instead, they write their selectors in Less or SCSS, which are both compiled to CSS before running in a browser. And, as I said, SCSS is either Turing complete or pretty close to it.

Comment: I doubt that "most" or even "many" is correct, given the number of questions about SCSS vs. questions about CSS on SO. And my bet would be that front-end programmers use SCSS, while graphic designers, less so (open question, maybe for the next survey).

Comment: I see it something like that `Graphics Designer <-- Web Designer --> Developer`. Maybe you are confusing *Graphics Designer* with *Web Designer*?

Comment: @RealSkeptic : [**According to a poll by Ashley Nolan with 689 respondants**](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/sass-vs-less/), 66% of the respondants use SCSS and only 13.5% use CSS without a pre-processor. Your argument that more questions on SO deal with CSS than with SCSS doesn't really mean anything, since CSS is a subset of Less & SCSS, and people who write Less & SCSS will also ask questions about CSS, but not the other way around.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt : Back in the 1990s, a "web designer" was someone who created websites. When building websites became more complex, the job of "web designer" got split into a "graphic design" & a "backend development" part. "Frontend development" is somewhere in the middle between "graphic design" & "backend development", and in many companies it's the graphic designer who is responsible for the "frontend development". Pure "frontend development" positions (= without graphic design or backend development roles) are pretty rare in my experience!

Comment: *Ashley nolan polled developers...* - which begs the question, really. This actually confirms my assumption, that frontend developers, who are versed in programming, use preprocessors.

Comment: Don't forget Fireworks! Some of us still have it installed even with a newer version of Creative Suite. Waiting for Adobe's Fireworks replacement to hit mass market *very* anxiously...

Comment: @JohnSlegers CSS is not a subset of LESS and SCSS. LESS and SCSS are subsets of CSS because they require (read: 'compile' to) CSS. You *can't* do Less or SCSS without eventually dealing with CSS. You can write CSS without ever learning about a *CSS* preprocessor. Also I'd be a bit skeptical of that poll; I've never heard of Ashley Nolan or KeyCDN. I doubt the sample size is representative of the majority of developers who deal with CSS on the whole. The site seems geared directly toward people who already use preprocessors are interested in them.

Comment: @JohnSlegers Testers not writing code? What about writing automated tests?

Comment: @TylerH That's not what "subset" means. "CSS is a subset of Less" strictly speaking means "all valid CSS is also valid Less", but in the context of the comment it was part of, suggests (rightly, I think) that all the questions you might legitimately ask about CSS, you might also ask about Less, but not vice versa. Same for SCSS.

Comment: @JohnSlegers So you regularly see graphical designers writing code, but have rarely seen a tester code?! 

In my experience it's the complete opposite. I've never, ever, seen a graphical designer write code in their daily work, but often come across testers who build quite intricate automated test systems (btw, as a software developer - we're all also testers, right?).

Comment: @RealSkeptic : As I said, pure "frontend development" positions (= without graphic design or backend development roles) are pretty rare in my experience! In almost every company I went to apply for a front-end position, they cared more about my design skills than my coding skills... even though it was always a position described as "frontend DEVELOPER"! There was but one exception, and they told me how rare it was for them to find any decent JavaScript coders... precisely because so many frontenders are just "graphic designers who can also write code"...

Comment: @TylerH : CSS is a subset of SCSS and Less in the sense that all valid CSS is also both valid SCSS and valid Less code, but not the other way around. With respect to graphic designers doing frontend code, see my previous comment in response to RealSkeptic.

Comment: @Fodder : You're probably right about testers. Maybe they should have been included in the survey as well?

Comment: @hvd : Thanks for clarifying my position.

Comment: @PärSvanström : You're probably right about testers. With respect to graphic designers writing code, see my last comment in response to RealSkeptic.

Comment: I agree that usually the frontend developer is also required to be a backend developer, and named "fullstack" developer at that. But in my experience, the frontend developer usually doesn't design or program deep aspects of the backend business logic, but rather stays on the shallow REST level. Frankly, I've never met a graphic designer who had a clue in development, and even CSS and HTML have been mostly "just products of tools" than anything else. YMMV. I think we are arguing based on personal experience rather than concrete facts. I'll stick to disagreeing with you...

Comment: @RealSkeptic : A lot of websites are built by marketing agencies. In my experience, they typically hire graphic designers for the entire frontend. Web app companies are more inclined to have their frontend done by (full stack) backend developers, but they're much less common. Then there's IT consultancy companies. I suppose they're more likely to have pure frontend dev position (as they're usually bigger companies), but I can't remember ever having encountered one during my job hunts... ;-)

Comment: @RealSkeptic : (continued) And yes, maybe my experience doesn't reflect the IT business as a whole. Ï'm sure the IT scene here in Belgium is different from the IT scene in India, in Bulgaria, in Uganda or in California. Still, I'm pretty sure that what I'm describing accurately reflects at least the situation here in Belgium.

Comment: @RealSkeptic [HTML/CSS is turing complete](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2497146/4639281)

Comment: [**Should Designers Know How To Code?**](https://blog.designveloper.com/2017/03/24/coding-designers/)

Answer (score -6):

### Your inference is too strong

At least based on the link you've included. It links to the "Developer Roles" section where respondents identified their "Developer Type", but it doesn't say *software* developer. I think you made that (totally understandable) assumption based on the context of StackOverflow.

Let's loosen your inference:

**Since when is a graphics designer a <strike>software</strike> developer?**

My gut says that's probably okay, but let's look at a definition:

> a person or thing that develops something.
>
> — [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=define+developer) (quoting some other dictionary)

Based on that, I'd agree with anyone who said, "Graphics designers are developers."

Comment: In the context of Stackoverflow, "development" means "software development". Not "property development", "career development", "muscle development" or... "content development".

Comment: @Bohemian The survey doesn't really lie within the context of Stack Overflow. Many of the questions were open to those who had never used Stack Overflow before.

Answer (score -7):

Like @ricksmt already said, the survey isn't about *software* developers at all. Here's some evidence:

- In the introduction there is a clear distinction between usage of "developers" when talking about the people who took the survey and "software developers" when talking about Stack Overflow users.
- You talk about the developer roles section, but have you seen the rest? Under "Specific Developer Types" → "Other Occupations" there are things like "Analyst or consultant", "Educator or academic", "Designer or illustrator" and even "Marketing or sales manager". Those titles don't imply software development at all.
- Under "Years since learning to code", the last sentence ends with "...adults with little to no programming experience can now more easily transition to a career as a developer.". Again, indicating this survey was not meant for only software developers and that the term "developer" in this context does not necessarily mean someone with programming experience.

A lot of questions *do* ask about coding/programming. So I guess it's fair to say the survey was meant for any kind of developer, but mainly asks about that developer's coding. Like one could do a survey for all US residents, but mainly ask questions related to life in a city.

Comment: For your second point, the section on Other Occupations is much more likely to have meant "not professionally a developer, but somehow ended up writing code anyway" (a reasonably common eventuality, especially for the listed occupations). For your third point, "it is now easier for non-programmers to become (not software) developers" is incoherent and thus clearly not what was meant at all. There is no reason to suppose that a lack of programming experience would hinder someone from getting a job that doesn't involve programming, but that's exactly what your interpretation would assume.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I see what you mean by the second point, but you misinterpret my reasoning in my third point. The sentence I quoted is about "adults with little **to no** programming experience", implying there are people with no programming experience filling out the survey.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. The statement in the survey is that a previous rule — that non-programmers have a harder time becoming (software) developers because they lack programming experience — is fading. Changing it up in the way you suggest makes it nonsensical, as though non-programmers used to have a harder time getting jobs as (non-software) developers because of their lack of programming experience. This assertion wouldn't make any sense, so the meaning of "developer" there *must* be **software** developer. Not everyone taking the survey need actually be a developer.